# How can I parse an XML array with and without wrapper to Java Object?

Tags: xml, spring-boot

I would like to parse XML I get from RMQ server to a Java Object

However, since it's my first time, it's not really working out well.

My XML example is as below.

```
<Message>
    <Header>
        <Type>36</Type>
        <MsgGuid>28b21e84-d922-4cf8-ab43-57acb6528e31</MsgGuid>
        <ServerTimestamp>1599191764</ServerTimestamp>
    </Header>
    <MessageBody>
        <Events>
            <Event FixtureId="5875134">
                <Fixture LastUpdate="2020-08-29T20:51:02.873Z">
                    <Sport Id="452674" Name="Cricket" />
                    <Location Id="143" Name="Finland" />
                    <League Id="38718" Name="Finnish Premier League" />
                    <StartDate>2020-08-30T12:00:00.000Z</StartDate>
                    <Status>1</Status>
                    <Participants>
                        <Participant Id="52439649" Name="Empire" Position="1" />
                        <Participant Id="52440581" Name="GYM Helsinki Gymkhana CC" Position="2" />
                    </Participants>
                </Fixture>
            </Event>
        </Events>
    </MessageBody>
</Message>
```

And my Java class designs are as below.

```
@Data
public class InPlayMessage {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Header")
    private Header header;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="MessageBody")
    private MessageBody body;

}

@Data
public class Header {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Type")
    private Integer type;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="MsgId")
    private Integer msgId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="MsgGuid")
    private String msgGuid;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ServerTimestamp")
    private Long serverTimestamp;

}

@Data
public class MessageBody {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Events", isAttribute = false)
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="KeepAlive", isAttribute = false)
    private KeepAlive keepAlive;

}

@Data
public class Event {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="FixtureId", isAttribute = true)
    private Integer fixtureId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Fixture")
    private Fixture fixture;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Markets")
    private List<Market> markets = new ArrayList<>();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Livescore")
    private Livescore livescore;

}
```

When I attempt to parse it with XmlMapper.readValue function,

The error occurs as below.

Seems like it's about array parsing but can't figure out how to fix it.

```
Unrecognized field "Events" (class com.ibin.inplay.domain.MessageBody), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "KeepAlive"])
```

Comment: Use this online generator and compare it to your own code. http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/